# Visual Studios "if Output Type == Windows Application then..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have some code in Visual Studios that I would like to be included compiled if the `Output Type` of the project is a `Windows Application`. If the type is `Class Library` I wish it to be ignored.

My main reason to do this is to include/exclude this

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 form = new Form1();

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

...and also some logic around closing the form in another class file, so that closing the form closes the application, whereas if it was a Class Library, it wouldn't.

I only want the `Main()` to be included and the form shown if its a Windows Application, otherwise don't.

Comment: This sounds like you're mixing reusable library code with application code. What does your library do exactly?

Comment: Do you actually compile your entry-point assembly as different application types?  Or is this a theoretical question?

Comment: @Stijn No at all. This is a library which is a plugin for another application. It has a GUI which is opened and I have this code to test the GUI without actually running the parent host.

Comment: Then this "code to test the GUI" should be in a separate assembly (so a separate project).

Comment: @DanPuzey not sure what the question is asking but the class that the snippet above is it gets compiled regardless of Output Type.

Comment: @Stijn since all I need to do is open the form as show in the snippet, I was hoping to avoid having a new project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just no point in doing this.  That Main() method is only ever going to run when the assembly is built as an EXE project.  If it is built as a class library then it is just an unused method that nobody is ever going to call and is never going to get jitted.  So there's no point in complicating your build to eliminate it.

If you really, really want to do this anyway then you'll have to use a conditional compilation symbol.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Conditional compilation symbols setting.  And #if in your code.

Also note that even building as a class library is unnecessary.  An assembly that was built as an EXE project works just as well as a class library.  Just add the reference.  Not having a real distinction between EXE and DLL assemblies is a very nice .NET goody.  One way you can see this in a regular solution that has an EXE project and a class library is by renaming the class library DLL to EXE.  And note that the program still works.

Comment: Having never used directives before, I assume you mean have a configuration for class library and a separate one for windows application.